# How to read files encoded with some extension of ASCII (ISO-8859-1) using in Node?

Tags: node.js, encoding, fs

I use chardet to detect the encoding of a file before reading it with fs. Up until today all files my application has read have been either `UTF-8` or `UTF-16LE`. These have been easy to map from chardet to Nodes BufferEncoding. I have used the `chardetToFsEncodings` in the code above map for that.

```
const chartdetToFsEncodings = new Map<string, BufferEncoding>([
  ["UTF-8", "utf8"],
  ["UTF-16LE", "utf16le"],
]);

const plausableEncodings = analyse(buffer).map((match) => match.name);

const supportedEncoding = plausableEncodings.find((name) => chartdetToFsEncodings.get(name)) as BufferEncoding;
if (supportedEncoding) {
  resolve({
    path,
    data: buffer.toString(supportedEncoding),
  });
} else {
  reject(new Error("File encoding not recognized"));
}
```

But what is a good approach when chardet encounters an encoding that does not have an obvious analog in BufferEncodings? Like today I encoutnered `iso-8859-2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what is a good approach when chardet encounters an encoding that does not have an obvious analog in BufferEncodings?

You need to write a decoder in these cases:

```js
var iso88592 = require('iso-8859-2') // https://www.npmjs.com/package/iso-8859-2

const chartdetToFsEncodings = new Map([
  ['UTF-8', 'utf8'],
  ['UTF-16LE', 'utf16le'],
  ['iso-8859-2', function decodeIso88592 (buffer) {
    return iso88592.decode(buffer.toString('binary'))
  }]
])

const plausableEncodings = analyse(buffer).map((match) => match.name)

const supportedEncoding = plausableEncodings.find((name) => chartdetToFsEncodings.get(name))
if (supportedEncoding) {
  let data
  if (typeof supportedEncoding === 'function') {
    data = supportedEncoding(buffer)
  } else {
    data = buffer.toString(supportedEncoding)
  }

  resolve({ path, data })
} else {
  reject(new Error('File encoding not recognized'))
}
```

Usually, API accepts UTF8 because it manages all the chars, while `latin2` is a subset of it.